# Text overlapping on widow size change?

Tags: html, css

I used a responsive template to create a restaurant website.

When shrinking the window to its thinnest form the menu prices overlap the text.

I tried absolute positioning and altering the width and height percentages but had no luck.

Is there a way I can keep the smaller window the same as what it looks like normally?

I've attached a photo of what it should look like and what it looks like when the window is shrunk.

[image: What it currently looks like when shrunk:]

[image: What it should look like:]

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
  <!--banner-->
  <section id="banner">
    <div class="darken">
      <header id="header">
        <div class="container">
          <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <a href="#about">About Us</a>
            <a href="#hours">Hours</a>
            <a href="#menu-list">Menu</a>
            <a href="#reviews">Reviews</a>
          </div>
          <!-- Use any element to open the sidenav -->
          <span onclick="openNav()" class="pull-right menu-icon">☰</span>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="inner text-center">
            <h3 class="logo-name">The Chow Wagon</h3>
            <p>(731) 989-7569</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- / banner -->

  <!--about-->
  <section id="about" class="section-padding">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center marb-35">
          <h5 class="header-h">Our Story</h5><br>
          <p class="header-p"> We are a small, family owned business bringing a lot of flavor to Henderson,
            Tennessee. The Chow Wagon is a a staple of hometwon fast food, serving
            everythign from old-fashioned hamburgers to salads. Come get a taste
            of our classic and state-wide known food! </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--/about-->

  <!-- hours -->
  <section id="hours">
    <div class="bg-color" class="section-padding">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 text-center" style="padding:60px;">
            <h1 class="header-h">Hours of Operation</h1>
            <p class="header-p">Monday: 10:30 AM - 10:30 PM <br><br> Tuesday: 10:30 AM - 10:30 PM <br><br>              Wednesday: 10:30 AM - 10:30 PM <br> <br> Thursday: 10:30 AM - 10:30
              PM <br><br> Friday:10:30 AM - 12:00 AM <br><br> Saturday: 10:30 AM
              - 12:00 AM <br><br> Sunday: 12:00 - 10:30 PM </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--/ hours -->

  <!-- menu -->
  <section id="menu-list" class="section-padding">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center marb-35">
          <h5 class="header-h">Menu </h5>
          <p class="header-p">
        </div>
        <div id="Container">
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">Hamburger</p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;"  class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$2.35</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">Cheeseburger</p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;"  class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$2.15</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">Jumbo Hamburger</p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$3.35</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">Jumbo Cheeseburger</p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$3.75</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">Ham & Cheese Sandwich</p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$2.45</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">Jumbo Ham & Cheese Sandwich</p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$3.45</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">Jumbo Ribeye Steak  Sandwich</p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;"  class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$5.25</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">Chicken Sandwich</p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$3.95</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">Chicken Bits and Fries</p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$4.95</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">Fish Sandwich</p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$3.00</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title" >Fish and Fries</p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$4.25</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-2 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title" >Shrimp and Fries</p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$5.50</span>
            </span>

          </div>
          <div class="mix category-2 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">Hot Dog</p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$2.05</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-2 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">Corn Dog</p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$1.60</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-3 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">Chef Salad</p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$4.40</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-3 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">French Fries</p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$1.60</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-3 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">Onion Rings</p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$1.60</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-3 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                <p2 class="menu-title">Fried Mushrooms</p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$2.75</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">Tater Tots</p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$1.60</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">9-Inch Cheese Pizza </p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$5.05</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">12-Inch Cheese Pizza </p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$6.75</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix c   category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">9-Inch Sausage Pizza </p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$10.50</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">12-Inch Sausage Pizza </p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$13.50</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">9-Inch Pepperoni Pizza </p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$10.50</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">12-Inch Pepperoni Pizza  </p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$13.50</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix   category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">9-Inch Bacon Pizza </p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$10.50</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">12-Inch Bacon Pizza </p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$13.50</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">9-Inch Beef Pizza </p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$10.50</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">12-Inch Beef Pizza </p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$13.50</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">9-Inch Beef Pizza </p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$10.50</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">12-Inch Beef Pizza </p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$13.50</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">9-Inch Mushroom Pizza </p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$10.00</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">12-Inch Mushroom Pizza </p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$12.00</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">9-Inch Pizza with Peppers   </p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$10.00</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">12-Inch Pizza with Peppers </p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$12.00</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">9-Inch Deluxe Pizza </p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$7.75</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="mix category-1 menu-restaurant" data-myorder="2">
            <span class="clearfix">
                        <p2 class="menu-title">12-Inch Deluxe Pizza </p2>
                        <span style="left: 166px; right: 44px;" class="menu-line"></span>
            <span class="menu-price">$9.75</span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <!--/ menu -->


  <!-- reviews -->
  <section id="reviews">
    <div class="bg-color" class="section-padding">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 text-center" style="padding:60px;">
            <h1 class="header-h">Our Customers say...</h1>
            <p class="header-p">"I ate here yesterday for the first time. That was the best burger I've
              had since moving here 3 1/2 years ago. The staff was friendly and the
              food made fresh. My only complaint is I couldn't eat more. I will most
              definitely be back." - Dorothy </p> <br>
            <p class="header- p">
              "Great food at a great price! I've never been disappointed!" - John </p>
            <br>
            <p class="header-p">"Best place to eat in Henderson, TN." - Rene</p><br>
            <p class="header-p">"It may be a small place on Main in Henderson, but boy, are those burgers
              delicious.... fresh right off the flat iron grill!" -Doralynn </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-bottom:60px;">
            <div class="item active left">
              <div class="content-holder">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--/ reviews -->


  <!-- footer -->
  <footer class="footer text-center">
    <div class="footer-top">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 text-center">
          <div class="widget">
            <h4 class="widget-title">THe Chow Wagon</h4>
            <p class="header-p">241 W Main St
              <br>Henderson, Tennessee 38340</p>
            <div class="social-list">
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
            <p class="copyright clear-float">
              © Delicious Theme. All Rights Reserved
              <div class="credits">
                <!--
                  All the links in the footer should remain intact.
                  You can delete the links only if you purchased the pro version.
                  Licensing information: https://bootstrapmade.com/license/
                  Purchase the pro version with working PHP/AJAX contact  form: https://bootstrapmade.com/buy/?theme=Delicious
                -->
                Designed by
                <p2 href="https://bootstrapmade.com/">BootstrapMade</p2>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- / footer -->

  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
  <script src="contactform/contactform.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post your actual code?

Comment: Sorry! It's added!

Comment: Use `Flex` it will support responsive also.

Comment: It's better than you can add display: flex property. and add your css.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong markup here.Learn to use bootstrap grid system.Make your html like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <!-- Item Goes here -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <!-- Rate Goes here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way your items won't collapse and overwrite each other.
[Learn grids from here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_templates.asp) :

Answer (score 0):

Use `Flex` property here I added sample code using Flex.

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: columns;
  
}
.item {
  flex: 1;
  color: #ccc;
}
.amount{ 
  flex: 1;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <h2>Humburger</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="amount">
    <h2>$2.53</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <h2>Hot Dog</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="amount">
    <h2>$5.53</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <h2>Stef Salad</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="amount">
    <h2>$2.53</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```